# jQuery, Razor, Variables, URLs... How to use @Url.Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, routes

I have a **CodesController** and the Index action looks like this.

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, string manufacturerName)
```

I want the URL to look like **http://www.domain.com/codes/[id]/[manufacturerName]** but with the code I currently am using it turns out to look like **http://www.domain.com/codes/[id]?manufacturerName=[manufacturerName]**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#btnNext').click(function () {
            var _id = $('#ddlManufacturers').val();
            var _manufacturerName = $('#ddlManufacturers').text();
            var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Codes", new { id = "_id", manufacturerName = "_manufacturerName" })'
            .replace('_id', _id).replace('_manufacturerName', _manufacturerName.toLowerCase().trim());
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
```

This is how I am doing it now and not sure how to properly do it so the URL turns out the way I want. The code

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you will need to add an route like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CodesRoute",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{manufacturerName}",
    new { controller = "Codes",  action = "Index",
        manufacturerName = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

After that you can use [`Html.RouteLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) or [`Url.RouteUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

As you are using it JavaScript  `Url.RouteUrl` will be useful

```
var url = '@Url.RouteUrl("CodesRoute", new { id = "_id", manufacturerName = "_manufacturerName" })'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need a new route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: null,
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{manufacturerName}",
    defaults: new { 
        controller = "Home", 
        action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional, 
        manufacturerName = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```